# How to use JavaScript or/and PHP, to detect a website/page being stolen/cloned and then redirect reader back to my website

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, copy-protection, data-protection

I found hundreds of cloned versions of my website.

Whoever is doing that are using some code that clones my web pages, changes my website name mydomain.com to clone1.com, clone2.com, clone3.com etc and this makes it impossible to use a simple JS or PHP to check if the header URL is = to mysite.com then redirect.

It also does not work using the .htaccess

For this reason I have created this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.href== "http://clone1.com/cat1/{{{ $title->id }}}-{{ (Str::slug($title->title)) }}/cat2/{{ $se->n }}/cat3/{{ $episode->ep_n }}") 
{
   window.location.href = 'http://google.com/'; 
}
</script>
```

This script completes its purpose but is too long and is also very restrictive because it must contain the exact URL.

**I'm looking to do this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.href== "http://
//contains this part in its URL
clone1.com , clone2.com , clone3.com , clone4.... 
}}") 
    {
       window.location.href = 'http://google.com/'; 
    }
    </script>
```

How can I create a global JS (JavaScript), that would detect if the current page is not on my domain and then redirect the reader to my domain and the same page?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Best Solution - Early Detection**

Depending on your main traffic source, it is possible to detect who is scrapping you and block them based on their IP, Headers, number of page views and other data, using PHP & HTACCESS.

I really like this answer on the StackOverflow, that discusses almost all the options available for early detection.

[How to detect fake users ( crawlers ) and cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257584/how-to-detect-fake-users-crawlers-and-curl#answer-12401278)

**2. Plugins & Extensions for Open Source Content Management Systems**

***Wordpress***

If using Wordpress CMS, you can try some plugins, like WordFence, that can detect and block fake Google Crawlers, block based on the number of page views etc.

***Other CMS***

If you can't find a similar solution for your CMS of choice, consider to ask a community for a help with creating the solution like that, as I believe many people could benefit from it.

**3. Solution for already stolen content with JavaScript**

Sometimes the easiest road to hide something in JS, is to actually HIDE something by OBFUSCATING and by hiding in multiple important files. For example, obfuscate some important file on your website without which the website just wouldn't work properly.

*For example, put an obfuscated version of the code below somewhere in JS file in the header, Obfuscate this code using any free services online or download your own library on Github:*

**Non-Obfuscated:**

```
w='mysite.com'; // Current URL e.g. 'mysite.com/category1/page2/'
function check_origin(){   
   var check = 587;
   if(window.location.hostname != w){
       window.location.href = w;
   }
   return check;
}
var check = check_origin();
```

**Obfuscated example:**

```
var _0x303e=["\x6D\x79\x73\x69\x74\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x68\x6F\x73\x74\x6E\x61\x6D\x65","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x68\x72\x65\x66"];w= _0x303e[0];function check_origin(){var check=587;if(window[_0x303e[2]][_0x303e[1]]!= w){window[_0x303e[2]][_0x303e[3]]= w};return check}var check=check_origin()
```

Now put an additional code in some Footer JS File, to verify the code above wasn't modified in any way:

**Non-Obfuscated example:**

```
 if(w!=='mysite.com'||check == false || typeof check == 'undefined' || check !== 587 ){
    window.location.href = 'mysite.com';
}
```

**Obfuscated:**

```
var _0x92bb=["\x6D\x79\x73\x69\x74\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x75\x6E\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6E\x65\x64","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E"];if(w!== _0x92bb[0]|| check== false||  typeof check== _0x92bb[1]|| check!== 587){window[_0x92bb[3]][_0x92bb[2]]= _0x92bb[0]}
```

I have used free online service from Google's search results for the term "Free Online JS Obfuscator:

https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx

**4. Fight thieves with available methods e.g. Request a Ban from Search Engines – The Digital Millennium Copyright Act of 1998**

Here is a blog-post that describes what to do when someone is stealing your content.

https://lorelle.wordpress.com/2006/04/10/what-do-you-do-when-someone-steals-your-content/

You can investigate who is doing that and report them to their partners, search engines, advertisers - to disrupt their business.

Depending on their country of origin and yours, it is maybe even possible to sue them and win.

Comment: Your solution dont work but YOUR idea about using an "obfuscated code" is an step forward to solve this problem because using an obfuscated code like this - if(window.location.hostname != 'mysite.com'){
    window.location.href = 'http://google.com/';
} directly in the page result in this url clonesite.com/...path.../mysite.com of corse, this will show an 404 in the clone page and reload forever ... DONT redirect to google.com - You can help???

Comment: Just store an original URL inside the obfuscated code and then redirect to that URL if something is not matching your checks.
So w='mysite.com'; would actually need to be an original URL of each page.
For example w='mysite.com/category1/page2/';
Also, I am not sure I understand you correctly. My solution is if you are worrying someone is stealing your content. If someone is stealing your content I would advise doing that, if it is for something else, then I am not getting that at all.

Comment: @ivan, I haven't realised you are using PHP, so I have cleaned up your question (just some spelling mistakes) and added some other solutions to my answer, I hope this will help many people

Answer (score 1):

why not check if hostname is your ?

```
if(window.location.hostname != 'mysite.com'){
    window.location.href = 'http://google.com/';
}
```

Comment: beacause in the clone website - mysite.com will be rewritten and this code will be: if(window.location.hostname != 'CLONE.com'){
    window.location.href = 'http://google.com/';
} -----Please read the post.